Slurm command to see node ID
I have a program that crashes for unknown reasons on a cluster. I have the feeling that it could be something that has to do with the use of a specific node(s). Is there a command to see on which nodes of the cluster a completed job has been running (I mean the node ID)? I would like to check if by any chance the job is run always on the same nodes.

The sacct command can be used to query the accounting database:
sacct --start=2024-10-01 --format jobid,state,nodelist

With the --format, you can specify the columns that you want to see. The --start allows looking at past jobs (by default, sacct will only show jobs for the current day)

That's a completely valid answer, I just wonder if there are possible alternatives if the slurm accounting storage happens to be disabled on a certain cluster?

Then what you can do is run srun hostname or echo $SLURM_JOB_NODELIST  at the beginning of your job to list the nodes in the allocation in the job output file.
